# How to increase the size of a font

Tags: luatex, fontsize

I'm writing a document with Adobe Caslon Pro and I get the impression that words are a little bit smaller than what I get with Times New Roman, for instance. Any idea of how to increase the height of the letters?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "kern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["quoteright"] = { ["a"] = 150 , ["eacute"] = 150 , ["o"] = 150 },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}[Scale=1.2]`

Comment: The fonts are designed by professionals; not a good idea to fiddle with them.

Comment: That's what editors do, though.